# two identical graphs considered not equal

Tags: networkx

using networkx,

> The MultiGraph and MultiDiGraph classes allow you to add the same
>   edge twice

So I guess it implies the basic class `Graph()` ignores multiple edges.

I did a test, and found it does ignore multiply edges, however adding same edge twice makes the graph object different. Can somebody explain why? Thanks

```
import networkx as nx

G1 = nx.Graph()
G1.add_edge(1, 2)
G1.edges() # [(1, 2)]
G1.degree(1) # 1

G2 = nx.Graph()
G2.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 2)])
G2.edges() # [(1, 2)]
G2.degree(1) # 1

G1==G2 # False
```

Comment: Aric's answer is the right one.  Something that may help you see it better would be to create `G2` with *exactly* the same command as `G1`:   `G2 = nx.Graph()`       `G2.add_edge(1, 2)`     `G1==G2` will still give you `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graphs are isomorphic (have the same structure) but are different Python objects.  You can test isomorphism with `nx.is_ismorphic`

```
import networkx as nx

G1 = nx.Graph()
G1.add_edge(1, 2)
G1.edges() # [(1, 2)]
G1.degree(1) # 1

G2 = nx.Graph()
G2.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 2)])
G2.edges() # [(1, 2)]
G2.degree(1) # 1

print G1==G2 # False
print repr(G1),repr(G2)
print nx.is_isomorphic(G1,G2)

#OUTPUT
# False
#<networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x7fda3174c050> <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x7fda3463e890>
#True
```